# How to get boost::asio::use_future to return a boost::future?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, future

The boost library defines a `boost::future` type, and defines a type `boost::asio::use_future` for returning futures from async methods, eg:

```cpp
std::future<std::size_t> my_future
  = my_socket.async_read_some(my_buffer, boost::asio::use_future);
```

but it's returning a `std::future`.

How do I get it to return a `boost::future` instead?

Comment: This is no longer a duplicate as `boost::asio` has changed sufficiently that the old answer is no longer applicable. It would be really good if someone could have another go at this.